# Implement `Copy` trait for `Option<Box<Struct>>`

Tags: rust, hashtable, ownership

I'm trying to implement a simple hash table with external chaining in Rust but having trouble with the table declaration. I declared the table as such:

```
static mut _HASH_TABLE: [Option<Box<MemoryMap>>; (std::u16::MAX -1) as usize] = [None; (std::u16::MAX -1) as usize];
```

with the `MemoryMap` being a dynamic linked list

```
pub struct MemoryMap {
    entry: SimpleEntry,
    next: Option<Box<MemoryMap>>,
}

impl MemoryMap {
    pub fn new(init_key: String, init_value: Box<dyn Storable>) -> MemoryMap {
        MemoryMap {
            entry: SimpleEntry::new(init_key, init_value),
            next: None,
        }
    }
//...
}

pub struct SimpleEntry {
    key: String,
    value: Box<dyn Storable>,
}

impl SimpleEntry {
    pub fn new(key: String, value: Box<dyn Storable>) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry { key, value }
    }
//...
}
```

That said, I get this error

```
5 | static mut _HASH_TABLE: [Option<Box<MemoryMap>>; (std::u16::MAX -1) as usize] = [None; (std::u16::MAX -1) as usize];
  |                                                                                                                                                           ^^^^ the trait `Copy` is not implemented for `Box<MemoryMap>`
  |
  = note: required for `Option<Box<MemoryMap>>` to implement `Copy`
  = note: the `Copy` trait is required because this value will be copied for each element of the array
```

and I can't understand why elements of the arrays have to be copied since I was expecting the array taking ownership of the `Box<MemoryMap>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't understand why elements of the arrays have to be copied since I was expecting the array taking ownership of the `Box<MemoryMap>`

When you write

```
[None; (std::u16::MAX -1) as usize]
```

the system needs to take the one value you gave it, and duplicate it `std::u16::MAX - 1` times in order to fill the array. [To do that, it uses `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html):

> A repeat expression `[x; N]`, which produces an array with `N` copies of `x`. The type of `x` must be `Copy`.

That can not work here because even if the `None` value is trivial, as far as Rust is concerned [`Option<T>` implements `Copy` iff `T` implements `Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Copy-for-Option%3CT%3E), and `Box<_>` does not implement `Copy`. So you need to implement an alternate initialisation method. Like the one linked by @cafce25, or using [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/) / [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) in order to have a global which is (lazy-) initialised at runtime, and would likely be something like a `Vec`.

Though frankly I don't get why you're even creating a global mutable thing, let alone one initialised a fixed 65k entries (of 64 bit pointers).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I didn't think about that. I don't have a particular reason for trying this out other than learning. Just to see what I can and can't do with Rust.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, can you suggest me a good implementation of Hash table with external chaining in Rust? I was looking at the implementation of HashMap in the standard library but that uses quadratic probing. That's why I was trying to see how I could implement one.

Comment: "Just to see what I can and can't do with Rust." I'm sorry to report mutable globals is definitely a big no-no in Rust. Can't help you wrt externally chained hash tables either, the only ones I can think of which might be would be the concurrent ones, sorry.

Comment: It's ok. I will just play around with it some more. Thanks for your time!